# What is the possible error for this retrofit code? I can't understand the connection of my API and MOBILE

Tags: json, api, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

I would like to find out the error is from my code or from my api.

This is my API CLASS:

```
      import retrofit2.Call;
      import retrofit2.http.Body;
      import retrofit2.http.POST;

      public interface Api {


          @POST("/api/Database/NewLocation")
          Call<MapDetails> mapDetailLocation(@Body MapDetails mapDetails);

          @POST("/api/Registration/RegisterDevice")
          Call<RegisterDetails> registerDetails(@Body RegisterDetails                     
           registerAllDetails);

      }
```

SETTER CLASS:

```
      import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

      public class MapDetails {
          @SerializedName("SerialNumber")
          private String serialNumber;
          @SerializedName("Coordinate1")
          private String coordinate1;
          @SerializedName("Coordinate2")
          private String coordinate2;
          @SerializedName("DateTime")
          private String dateTime;
          @SerializedName("Speed")
          private String speed;
          @SerializedName("Port")
          private Integer Port;



          public MapDetails(String serialNumber, String coordinate1, String           
           coordinate2,
                            String dateTime, String speed, Integer port) {
              this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
              this.coordinate1 = coordinate1;
              this.coordinate2 = coordinate2;
              this.dateTime = dateTime;
              this.speed = speed;
              Port = port;
          }

          public String getSerialNumber() {
              return serialNumber;
          }

          public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
              this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
          }

          public String getCoordinate1() {
              return coordinate1;
          }

          public void setCoordinate1(String coordinate1) {
              this.coordinate1 = coordinate1;
          }

          public String getCoordinate2() {
              return coordinate2;
          }

          public void setCoordinate2(String coordinate2) {
              this.coordinate2 = coordinate2;
          }

          public String getDateTime() {
              return dateTime;
          }

          public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
              this.dateTime = dateTime;
          }

          public String getSpeed() {
              return speed;
          }

          public void setSpeed(String speed) {
              this.speed = speed;
          }

          public Integer getPort() {
              return Port;
          }

                    public void setPort(Integer port) {
              Port = port;
          }
      }
```

Activity Class:

```
                    MapDetails mapDetails = new MapDetails("1807200005", 
                    lat,lon, currentDateTimeString, "0", 9090);
                    setLocation(mapDetails);



                   private void setLocation(MapDetails mapDetails) {
                      initializeRetrofit(mapDetails);
                     }

                private void initializeRetrofit(MapDetails mapDetails) {
                    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("http://undefine.apisecure.data[![enter image description here][1]][1]")
                      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

                    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

                    Api locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);

                    SetMapLocationApiCaller(locate, mapDetails);


                }

                private void SetMapLocationApiCaller(Api locate, MapDetails 
                mapDetails) {

                    Call<MapDetails> call =                      
                    locate.mapDetailLocation(mapDetails);
                    executeCallAsynchronously(call);
                }

                private void executeCallAsynchronously(Call call) {
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<MapDetails>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<MapDetails> call, 
                         Response<MapDetails> response) {

                            Snackbar.make(view,""+ response, 
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                            Snackbar.make(view, ""+t.getMessage(), 
                                      Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

                        }
                    });


                }
```

On my app  , this is the response on my app:[image]

but its not added to my sql. But if am using insomia, it would have send the data I've created to the database.[image]

this data was inserted via insomia not on mobile.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost reached to the solution. But, you made little mistake while passing parameters to the API request.

As I can see from the screenshot of Insomia app, that API requires JSONArray as parameter but you're sending JSONObject.

Sample JSON parameter

```
[
    {
        "SerialNumber" : "1234",
        "Coordinate1" : "12.7845874",
        "Coordinate2" : "76.4584578",
        "DateTime" : "2018-11-14 08:45:00",
        "Speed" : "0",
        "Port" : 9090
    }
]
```

According to the above JSON structure you need to change the `Api.java` class to something like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

import java.util.List;  // add import

public interface Api {

    @POST("/api/Database/NewLocation")
    Call < MapDetails > mapDetailLocation(@Body List<MapDetails> mapDetails);

                                            //  ^^^^ changes here

    @POST("/api/Registration/RegisterDevice")
    Call < RegisterDetails > registerDetails(@Body RegisterDetails registerAllDetails);

}
```

Add `List<MapDetails>` to `mapDetailLocation()` method parameter.

And in Activity or Fragment use above method like this:

```
//......
// part of the code

MapDetails mapDetails = new MapDetails("1807200005", lat, lon, currentDateTimeString, "0", 9090);

List<MapDetails> data = new ArrayList<>();

data.add(mapDetails);

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("<BASE_URL>")  // change base URL
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

Api locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);

Call<MapDetails> call = locate.mapDetailLocation(data);     // NOTICE THE CHANGES IN PARAMETER

call.enqueue(new Callback<MapDetails>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MapDetails> call, Response<MapDetails> response) {

        // do whatever you want

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

        // log the error message 

    }
});
```

Note: Please change base URL according to your requirement.

**Edit:**

Change method parameters in Activity from `MapDetails` to `List<MapDetails>`

```
// prepare data

MapDetails data = new MapDetails("1807200005", lat, lon, currentDateTimeString, "0", 9090);

// add it to ArrayList

List<MapDetails> mapDetails = new ArrayList<>();

mapDetails.add(data);

// pass it as an argument

private void setLocation(List<MapDetails> mapDetails) {
    initializeRetrofit(mapDetails);
}
```

Change method parameter in `initializeRetrofit()`

```
private void initializeRetrofit(List<MapDetails> mapDetails) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("<BASE_URL>")  // change base URL
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    Api locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    SetMapLocationApiCaller(locate, mapDetails);

}
```

Again change method parameter

```
private void SetMapLocationApiCaller(Api locate, List<MapDetails> mapDetails) {
    Call<MapDetails> call = locate.mapDetailLocation(mapDetails);
    executeCallAsynchronously(call);
}
```

Comment: ive chage it with my local api

Comment: upon the mobile, it passes true but not added in my database.... upon using insomnia(like postman), if i send the json object created i finnaly add the data on my database...

Comment: also i've try to postman sending json array via post on my api url... but its not working, only in insomnia via json object.

Comment: Did you try exact what I've mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Insomnia screenshot shows that you're sending `JSONArray` which starts with `[` and ends with `]`. If that works perfectly, you should read my answer properly (with comments). Check parameters of the method that I've mentioned in my answer. Use the same base URL which you're trying with Insomnia.

Comment: ohh sorry sir,  my mistake, wait sir :)

Comment: ive imported like this:
 
 @POST("/api/Database/NewLocation")
    Call<MapDetails> mapDetailLocation(@Body List<MapDetails> mapDetails);
 
and my activity:

             private void SetMapLocationApiCaller(Api locate, MapDetails mapDetails) {

                        Call<MapDetails> call = locate.mapDetailLocation((List<MapDetails>) mapDetails);
                        executeCallAsynchronously(call);
                    }

but ive got a error on the add parameter

Comment: this is the error message from the logcat com.julxian10.pakultie.fleetmanagement.Retrofit.MapDetails cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: I updated my answer. Please look closely into the answer and the sample snippet. (variables and parameters) I've used comments for better understanding please read it. Don't be in hurry to fix the problems. First understand the core concept. As I can see from your previous comments you're not noticing the code changes clearly and not understanding the error/warning from Android Studio IDE. This is free advice and it helps you to become a good programmer in my opinion. Don't take it as negative remark.

Comment: it ok now, sir, hmmm could you give me an tutorial /example to how to understand the difference betweeen codding of json array and json object via retrofit?

Comment: Does it work now? Sorry if my previous comment looked harsh. I wasn't trying to demotivate you. And about the tutorials start with Retrofit's [official doc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) as it's easy to understand and very simple. If you want other tutorials, you could try with [Future Studio](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit) as they've almost all the topics in Retrofit. I'm not forcing you to check _only_ these tutorials. You're always free to check other tutorials. Good luck and happy coding...